# Is StringBuilder a collection?

Tags: java, collections

I have to make a program which doesn't use Collections like ArrayList. I also have to make it as fast as possible, so I was wondering: is StringBuilder considered a collection? Using it would make my program much faster, so I need to know it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `StringBuilder` is not part of the `Collection`s API nor does it extend from any of the classes from the API.  If you did consider `StringBuilder` to be part of the collections API, you'd have to consider `String` and arrays as well :p

Comment: does it inherit from `Collection`?

Comment: What does "doesn't use Collections like ArrayList" mean?  You should use whatever classes you need.

Comment: @SLaks Sounds like homework (or challenge) to me

Comment: @SLaks this is obviously homework, the remedial question with no attempt at research should tip you off to that!

Comment: It's for a coding challenge, sorry to disappoint you @JarrodRoberson . They said that we couldn't use collections of any kind, and I was wondering if generally the StringBuilder class is regarded as one of those, even if it doesn't inherit from Collection. I guess the rules could have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you look at the source code for the StringBuilder class, you can see that it extends [AbstractStringBuilder](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java), which stores data in a plain character array and resizes it when necessary.